# Display the values of 2 foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, sql-view

I am creating a MySQL database which has a relation in the form of:

[image: database]

What I am trying to achieve is to create a view which displays the details of both couples at once, for example the column names would be:

```
|| P1_First_Name || P1_LastName || P1_Gender || P2_FirstName || P2_LastName || P2_Gender ||
```

However I am not sure how to do this. So far I have something along the lines of

```
CREATE VIEW CoupleDetails AS
SELECT People.`First Name`, People.`Last Name`, People.`Gender`
FROM Couples
LEFT JOIN People ON People.NI_Number = Couples.ni_person1;
```

Which works fine for getting the details of the first person. I've spent the last few hours trying to create a table which displays the columns I need but I cannot get something to work as I described above - and quite frankly I'm not sure what I'm meant to be doing! Could someone please provide me guidance in the correct direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join table `People` twice against table `Couples` since there are two columns of table `Couples` that are depended on table `People`.

I think the columns on table `Couples` are required (*or non-nullable*) because you cannot called a couple when there is only one person `:)`

```
CREATE VIEW CoupleDetails 
AS
SELECT  b.FirstName P1_FirstName,
        b.LastName P1_LastName,
        b.Gender = P1_Gender,
        c.FirstName P2_FirstName,
        c.LastName P2_LastName,
        c.Gender = P2_Gender
FROM    Couples a
        INNER JOIN People b
            ON a.ni_person1 = b.NI_Number
        INNER JOIN People c
            ON a.ni_person2 = c.NI_Number
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)